# Creating input when checking/clicking radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm new to jQuery and played a bit with what can I do with radio button. I want to create **ONLY** one input type when I click the <kbd>Notice</kbd> radio button. I already using many way to achieve this, but this is the only way I can do this, you can see the following code.

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Immediate" /> Immediate
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="others" value="Notice" /> Notice me in...
<br />
<div id="inputplace"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $("#others").click(function(){
        while($("#others").val()=="Notice")
        {
            var newElement = $(document.createElement('input')).attr({name:"noticeweeks", id:"noticeweeks"});   
            newElement.appendTo("#inputplace");

            $("#others").val("Notice me in...");
        }
    });
});
```

With that jQuery, I changed the value of the radio button into "Notice me in...", so the `while` function will stop creating a new element since the value has been changed.

Are there any others way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2):

- There's no need to use a `while` loop, as you only want to add the element once, after which the condition won't hold anymore. That's what `if` is for.
- There's a shorter way to create a new element

So I get to:

```
$(function() {
    $("#others").click(function() {
         if ($("#others").val() == "Notice") {
            var newElement = $('<input>')).attr({name:"noticeweeks", id:"noticeweeks"});   
            newElement.appendTo("#inputplace");    
            $("#others").val("Notice me in...");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah yeah, actually I already changed it to if already and it works, than you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can go about the "only once" part in a couple of ways:

1. Remove the event-listener once the new input has been added
2. Always have the extra input, but have it hidden, and show it when necessary
3. Have a closure variable that holds the input; if it's defined, don't redefine it

And more. I'd personally go with #2, because it means that your inputs are actually in the markup, while the javascript *only* defines behavior. That is, keep elements in the markup, style and layout in CSS, and behavior in JS - don't mix it

In other words:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Immediate" /> Immediate
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="others" value="Notice" /> Notice me in...
<br />
<!-- extra input, just hidden -->
<input type="text" name="noticeweeks" id="noticeweeks" value="" style="display: none" />
```

and the JS:

```
$(function(){
  // cache these!
  var radioButton = $("#others"),
      noticeWeeks = $("#noticeweeks");

  radioButton.change(function () { // listen for change - not click
    if( this.checked ) { // use the "raw" DOM property `checked`
      noticeWeeks.show();
    }
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W8Mp2/)

Of course, I get the feeling, that what you really want is to show the extra input, when "Notice me in..." is selected, and *hide* it when "Immediate" is selected.

In that case, the JS could be

```
$(function(){
  // cache these!
  var radioButtons = $("[name=radio1]"), // get both radiobuttons
      noticeWeeks  = $("#noticeweeks");

  radioButtons.change(function () {
    if( $(this).val() === "Notice" ) { // this time, we do need to check the value
      noticeWeeks.show();
    } else {
      noticeWeeks.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W8Mp2/1/)

Comment: Ah no, actually if I select to Immediate using the JS I will remove it using .remove()

But anyway, thanks a bunch I will try your way.

Comment: @Xtrader In that case, I'd use `noticeWeeks.prop('disabled', false).show();` and `noticeWeeks.prop('disabled', true).hide();` to show/hide _and_ enable/disable the input. That way it won't be visible _or_ submitted to the server when it's "turned off". Again, keep you markup in your markup; don't add and remove trivial stuff like this with JS.

Comment: Ah sorry, if I use prop will it creating an memory leak in IE 9? Because the documentation said so, should I use the .data() method?

Comment: @Xtrader No. `disabled` is a standard HTML attribute you're setting on the element, so `data` won't work. Use `.prop()` or `.attr()`. And read the documentation again: The memory leak only happens in IE _below_ version 9, and it _doesn't happen at all_ for a boolean values, which is what this is.